# Remote data model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, activerecord, model

i have model with validations, some methods, filters and so. Unfortunately the data are from API, so i need to overload the method which is pull the records from DB. Which method is that?

So far i have creation. Method create in active record's model is presisting new record. I just add method create to my model and it's creating records over the API. Now i want it for selecting the data.

Following code is example of what i already have (creation of records):

```
def create
  EmployeesApi.create(self.attributes.reject{|k,v| %w(id created_at updated_at).include? k })
end
```

I need it as low level as possible, because it has some relations and app specific validations. Moving also the relations and surrounding logic would mean integrate two existing systems and that's not ok in this case.

Another explanation:

I want to bypass the database for data of the model, but for association let everything as it was. The model's data are stored in another app/database/system.

I'll load model's own data by API and ActiveRecord will pair/load it's associations from local DB

Comment: Well I guess you're not looking for the `find()` method, right?

Comment: Sparda: It would be great if it works, but unfortunately i need to go more deep, because there is also cancan involved. After CanCan authorize, *where* will filter that records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If EmployeeApi would be modeled after [ActiveResource](https://github.com/rails/activeresource) you could possibly enhance it with [ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activemodel). Associations might work only in one way (from ActiveRecord to ActiveResource). It is also good to consider exceptions such as API is down.

Comment: Looks promising, dik. Will give it try tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is to pull some data from the DB before creating this record? or validate some DB field, maybe ensure a unique constrain or something.. Please look into the active record hooks/callbacks

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

You can do something like this:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_create :record_signup

    private
    def record_signup
      self.signed_up_on = Date.today
    end
end
```

Comment: No, I want to bypass the database for data of the model, but for association let everything as it was. The model's data are stored in another app/database/system

Comment: I see, so your data creator would be some sort of Proxy pattern. Makes sense.. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) . As for active record, you are looking into turning off persistance (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) ... more specific the persisted? method. Good luck

Comment: I am not turning off persistence. I have persistence already done. Now i need loading. But you're right about the Proxy patern